# IBM-Watson Text-to-speech API: Method failed with status code 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, api, text-to-speech, ibm-watson, watson-text-to-speech

**Overview**
Enable to use IBM Watson API with Python. I keep getting 403 error (forbidden) no matter which URL I used
I tried the following URLs:

- https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api
- https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/v1/synthesize
- https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/text-to-speech/api
- https://api.us-south.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com

But none of them work.

Code sample

```py
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
from ibm_watson.websocket import SynthesizeCallback
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator
from ibm_watson import ApiException

apikey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
url = 'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api'
try:
    authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(apikey)
    service = TextToSpeechV1(authenticator=authenticator)
    service.set_service_url(url)

    voices = service.list_voices().get_result()
    print(json.dumps(voices, indent=2))
except ApiException as ex:
    print("Method failed with status code " + str(ex.code) + ": " + ex.message)
```

I'm able to use the API via CURL.

**Expected behavior**
Getting a success response from the API

**Actual behavior**
Getting 403 (forbidden)

**Screenshots**
[image]

**SDK Version**
Latest

**Additional information:**

- OS: Windows 10
- Python 3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

As per the API documentation ( https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/text-to-speech?code=python#authentication ), it should be:

```py
url = 'https://api.us-east.text-to-speech.watson.cloud.ibm.com'
```